# How can I see what algorithm my android ssh client connected with?

Tags: security, ssh

I want to find out how secure my SSH connection from my android client is. 
Is it connecting with the latest encryption?

I connect to both linux and windows servers. While I can look for my clients IP in the server SSH logs, it would be nice if I could tell from my client what security methods it negotiated instead of having to dig through the logs.

Comment: You might want to ask this at some other Stack Exchange site, maybe https://security.stackexchange.com/ ? Stack Overflow is strictly on programming.

Comment: @Ammo That depends onther used SSH client and of course the server. Unfortunately you don't tell us anything as `SSH connection from my android client´ is not very specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about using an Android app, not developing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download `GSW Connectbot` android client,
 Make the connection, then go back to the home screen while the connection is running, long press on the host and select security info. It will give you a list of security items, Host Key Algorithm, Key Exchange, Cipher, MAC, etc. 
[You can get it from here](https://www.georgiasoftworks.com/connectbot-client-android)